# I get the wrong output during the collection process

Tags: java, android

I made an order application. When I mark the radio buttons, it adds like this, I want it to write normal numbers
Screen output like this I don't want it like this I want it to collect
made the sum wrong
[image: screen output like this]

```
        boolean checked=((RadioButton) view ).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.rb1:
            if (checked)
                pizza.setPizza_size_price(15);
            break;
            case R.id.rb2:
                pizza.setPizza_size_price(17);
                break;
            case R.id.rb3:
                pizza.setPizza_size_price(19);
                break;
            case R.id.rb6:
                if (checked)
                pizza.setIcecek(3);
                break;
            case R.id.rb7:
                pizza.setIcecek(2);
                break;
            case R.id.rb8:
                pizza.setIcecek(3);
                break;
            case R.id.rb11:
                if (checked)
                pizza.setPatates(5);
                break;
            case R.id.rb12:
                pizza.setPatates(6);
                break;
            case R.id.rb13:
                pizza.setPatates(7);
                break;
        }
        total.setText("Toplam Ücret:"+pizza.getPizza_size_price()+pizza.getIcecek()+pizza.getPatates()+"TL");
    }
```

Comment: we can't see your screenshot

Comment: I am sorry @JohnJoe can you see now

Comment: This switch hurts to look at. Why are you even using one big switch for multiple radio button groups? Just more of a nightmare to maintain

Comment: There are 3 will I open a different click and show each one there? @JimmyR.T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to get the sum of `pizza.getPizza_size_price()`, `pizza.getIcecek()` and `pizza.getPatates()` as output you have to add parenthesis:

```java
total.setText("Toplam Ücret:"+(pizza.getPizza_size_price()+pizza.getIcecek()+pizza.getPatates())+"TL");
```

Otherwise the numbers won't be sumed up but just appended to the string like `"15.0"+"3.0"+"6.0"` which then becomes `"15.03.06.0"`